# Invalid syntax error when calling method on new line

Tags: python, dataframe, graph

I wanted to create a world map and add my dataset into it. Its about deforestation. My hope was to show every country based on the data.

Here is what i did:

```
world_map = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')
chart = alt.Chart(world_map).mark_geoshape().encode(
    color=alt.Color('Annual net change in forest area:Q'),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('properties.name:N', title='Country'),
        alt.Tooltip('properties.pop_est:Q', title='Population')]
    ).properties(
    width=600,
    height=400
).project('naturalEarth1')
.transform_lookup(lookup="Entity", from_=alt.LookupData(Forest, 'Entity', ['Entity', 'Annual net change in forest area']))
chart.display()
```

What did i do wrong? When i try run it, i get the error:

```
Cell In [2], line 12
    .transform_lookup(lookup="Entity", from_=alt.LookupData(Forest, 'Entity', ['Entity', 'Annual net change in forest area']))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is sensible to new lines in statements like yours. If you'd like to write a continued call chain over multiple lines, you have to use the escape character (`\`) like this:

```py
some_object.some_method() \
    .another_method() \
    .yet_another_method()
```

In your case you have to use a `\` after `project('naturalEarth1')`.

Comment: Hey Thank you. It worked. At least i can see the world map, but i cant see the dataset which i want to combine with it. Any idea how to do it?